# Visual Studio becoming out of sync with the file system

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I was doing some refactoring today and accidentally renamed a class.

I realized my mistake and used undo.  After I was done I successfully built and ran my application.

No files were marked as being changed in the VS GUI.  I then committed my changes using AnkSNV.  The cruise control build promptly failed.

A bit of investigation revealed that even though VS was showing and had built my code using the old class names, the files on my disk (which were committed to SVN) had the rename change that I had undone saved to them.

This in turn broke dependencies outside of my open solution (realizing this would happen was why I undid the initial change).

Does anyone have a clue how this happened, and short of verifying my files outside of visuals studio to make sure that the changes I'm seeing there are the same as what I would be committing are identical?

Comment: I have found VS-"integrated" SVN solutions to be more trouble than they're worth for the exact reason you're experiencing.  It's certainly personal preference, but I much prefer Alt-Tabbing to Explorer to use TortoiseSVN and use helpful tools like "Repair Move" and "Repair Rename" in the Commit dialog.

Comment: @user2202911 if I'd found one, I'd've posted an answer.  I don't think I've seen it happen since upgrading to 2010 though.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I have found that source control clients integrated into Visual Studio are somewhat clunky when renaming files.

To be honest I've just come to expect it and have got used to it.

Comment: This wasn't a file rename, just a class rename within the file (were it not for the dependency issues that made me pull the change back there would've been file renames but I never got that far).